# jQuery hovering thumbnails but taking time to update main shot, has to catch up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for a better solution to fix this issue I am facing.

If you hover onto a thumbnail, it fades out larger shot and fades in the new one which is fine, but while going to a targeted thumbnail and your mouse hovers a few more it changes to those others your mouse went over and takes time to catch up. Is there any way to resolve this? Maybe some kind of timer or something, or maybe a better solution all together?

```js
if ($('#product_color_select li').hasClass("selected")) {
  var product_color_select_first = $("#product_color_select li.selected").attr('data-larger');
  $("#larger-colour").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(product_color_select_first);
  });
}

$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseover", function() {
  var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
  var thumbnail = $('#larger-colour');

  thumbnail.fadeOut("slow", function() {
    thumbnail.removeClass();
  });

  thumbnail.queue(function() {
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(select_product_swatch);
    $(this).dequeue();
  });

  thumbnail.fadeIn("slow");
});
```

```css
#product_color_select {
  width: 76%;
  float: left;
}
#product_color_select li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  text-indent: -999999em;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 2px 5px 0;
}
#larger-colour {
  float: right;
  max-width: 86px;
  width: 86px;
  height: 62px;
}
/* interior colours */

#product_color_select li.eco-weave,
#larger-colour.eco-weave {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/eco-weave.png');
}
#product_color_select li.aubergine-dream,
#larger-colour.aubergine-dream {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/aubergine-dream.png');
}
#product_color_select li.lime-citrus,
#larger-colour.lime-citrus {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/lime-citrus.png');
}
#product_color_select li.blue-jazz,
#larger-colour.blue-jazz {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/blue-jazz.png');
}
#product_color_select li.sakura-pink,
#larger-colour.sakura-pink {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/sakura-pink.png');
}
#product_color_select li.hot-chocolate,
#larger-colour.hot-chocolate {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/hot-chocolate.png');
}
#product_color_select li.tundra-spring,
#larger-colour.tundra-spring {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/tundra-spring.png');
}
#product_color_select li.black-sapphire,
#larger-colour.black-sapphire {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/black-sapphire.png');
}
#product_color_select li.luscious-grey,
#larger-colour.luscious-grey {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/luscious-grey.png');
}
#product_color_select li.wildberry-deluxe,
#larger-colour.wildberry-deluxe {
  background-image: url('http://2015.ambientlounge.com/design/themes/ambientlounge/media/images/swatches/mini/wildberry-deluxe.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="fabric-select" id="product_color_select">
  <li class=" aubergine-dream" data-value="745" data-larger="aubergine-dream" title="Aubergine Dream">Aubergine Dream</li>
  <li class=" black-sapphire" data-value="746" data-larger="black-sapphire" title="Black Sapphire">Black Sapphire</li>
  <li class=" wildberry-deluxe" data-value="727" data-larger="wildberry-deluxe" title="Wildberry Deluxe">Wildberry Deluxe</li>
  <li class=" tundra-spring" data-value="747" data-larger="tundra-spring" title="Tundra Spring">Tundra Spring</li>
  <li class="selected luscious-grey" data-value="744" data-larger="luscious-grey" title="Luscious Grey">Luscious Grey</li>
  <li class=" sakura-pink" data-value="743" data-larger="sakura-pink" title="Sakura Pink">Sakura Pink</li>
  <li class=" lime-citrus" data-value="748" data-larger="lime-citrus" title="Lime Citrus">Lime Citrus</li>
  <li class=" eco-weave" data-value="742" data-larger="eco-weave" title="Eco Weave">Eco Weave</li>
  <li class=" blue-jazz" data-value="749" data-larger="blue-jazz" title="Blue Jazz">Blue Jazz</li>
  <li class=" hot-chocolate" data-value="741" data-larger="hot-chocolate" title="Hot Chocolate">Hot Chocolate</li>
</ul>

<div id="larger-colour" class="aubergine-dream" style="display: block;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jzrft/86/)

```
 if ($('#product_color_select li').hasClass("selected")) {
  var product_color_select_first = $("#product_color_select li.selected").attr('data-larger');
  $("#larger-colour").fadeIn("fast", function() {
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(product_color_select_first);
  });
}

$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseover", function() {
  var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
  var thumbnail = $('#larger-colour');

  thumbnail.fadeOut("fast", function() {
    thumbnail.removeClass();
  });

  thumbnail.queue(function() {
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(select_product_swatch);
    $(this).dequeue();
  });

  thumbnail.fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Comment: It still does the same thing just fast... not the solution i needed really, need to change to which ever one you stop at and ideally not show any of the larger swatches when hovering over until you get to the swatch your wanting to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseover", function() {    
    $('#larger-colour').removeClass();    
    var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
    $('#larger-colour').addClass(select_product_swatch);    
     $('#larger-colour').stop(true, true).fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
$("#product_color_select li").on("mouseout", function() {
    var select_product_swatch = $(this).attr('data-larger');
    $('#larger-colour').stop(true, true).fadeTo("slow", 0);
    $('#larger-colour').removeClass();    
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7cxdkfon/)

Comment: Works much better, does not been to have the same fadeout fadein effect tough, possible we can do like that? doe snot seem to be slow

Comment: you can change speed to your ideal by changing : .fadeIn(1000); .fadeOut(500); instead of .fadeTo("slow", 1) and .fadeTo("slow", 0)